# How close do I have to be to get mini-crits with the BackScatter?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

Scout's new primary, the Backscatter, proports to do Mini-Crit damage when shots are made to the back **and** at close-range.

[image]

So far, I've gotten plenty of mini-crit experience from backshots, but not once have I seen a mini-crit occur when up-close and in a person's face.

How close do you have to be to get a non-backshot mini-crit with the Backscatter as the Scout?

Edit: It is possible that the "and" here means you must be behind AND close to your opponent, rather than one or the other.  If this is true, and can be confirmed, I'd like to know how close one needs to be to get mini-crit damage from behind.

Comment: I believe this is a conditional case. It doesn't say **or**, so you need to shoot from the back ***and*** close range to minicrit. being close doesn't minicrit nor just does shooting the back. You need both. I don't know for sure... Just using programmer logic..

Comment: @ I've been pretty far away and got minicrit damage (A whole 9 hp!), but maybe I was closer than I thought?  If you can confirm this, I'd definitely accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'm completely guessing... Never played tf2 before ;P

Comment: I can give you an answer when I get off work and can test it out myself. I'll probably use that map where people do the weapon test videos.

Comment: @Rapitor It's ambiguous. The english could be interpreted as: "Minicrits when (at back and close range)" or "(Minicrits when at back) and (Minicrits when at close range)"

Comment: For the record, the description got updated today, which removes the confusion of the "and" clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a quick test of mine, this is the max distance for Back Scatter mini-crits:

[image: representative screenshot]

I put the Soldier under the center of the light and crept closer until the shot was a mini-crit. I don't have the distance numbers, but hopefully this image is descriptive enough. To me it looks like about half Sentry visibility range; if so that's 512 Source units (the point where the distance modifier in the damage formula is 1.0).

And just to confirm, you cannot get mini-crits from the front with it. The "and" in the description means both conditions must be met. (I was confused about this too at first.)

Comment: I think source measures in hammer units. Is that about 512 hammer units?

Comment: Yeah I think the units are the same.